# Set next EditText focused and editable on KEY_DOWN

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a layout with two editexts. I need to set the second one focused and editable when the enter key is hit on the first one. I've got code for setting focus but I ***can't start typing*** when the second one gets the focus.

PS I also need edittext to be exactly one line height without possibility of making addtional rows. It works as well.
pss android 2.3

XML code:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            style="@style/profileLoginInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/email" android:ems="10" android:lines="1" android:maxLines="1" android:ellipsize="end">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

<EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            style="@style/profileLoginInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" android:hint="@string/password">
```

Java code :

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.email)).setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    switch (keyCode)
                    {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.password)).requestFocus();
                        return true;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: -its a, android:nextFocusDown="@id/editText2", remove '+' from id. And try again let me know hat happen..

Comment: it says that it can't find a resource - can u post a sample code with conditions I mentioned above?

Comment: Your code works fine in my case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be bugged when running this code on the emulator. However, it works on phones

Answer (score 24):

You're overthinking this. You can specify the order of the EditText inputs right in the XML without doing anything in Java.

Use the `android:nextFocusDown` param to specify which field you'd like to get focus when the user hits the enter key.

Comment: When I hit enter key nothing happens: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText2">

    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

Comment: Try `android:nextFocusForward="@+id/editText2"`. Also make sure, it's not a multi-line EditText.

Comment: i have used like `editText.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.editText1);`

Comment: I'm using View.FOCUS_FORWARD, so Sheharyar Naseer's answer solved my problem! I needed to tell my last edittext to set focus to first edittext.

Answer (score 12):

```
android:inputType="text"
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/..."
```

worked for me

Answer (score 4):

android:nextFocusDown
Worked fine for me
But removed the following Method only then its work:

```
editText1.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {

 @Override

public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
      if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||   
              actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
         editText2.requestFocus();
         return false;
      }

      return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides adding the + in front of id:

```
android:inputType="text"
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/..."
```

I also had to add:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```