# Edittext requestFocus() dynamically not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have multiple Edittexts on action next I have added nextFocus values in the xml.

But one edit text is either visible or invisible based on the state of under age checkbox value. So  I need to set focus on it afterr YYYY editext dynammically. **But dynamically the requestFocus() is not working.**

**What I need to do on click of Next**

[image]

**This Email view is visible only when under 18 check box is unchecked.**

> What happends on next button click after YYYY edittext : control goes
>   to username Edittext. I cant use FocusNext in xml as the app crashes
>   whenever the email textview is GONE

```
 dobYearEt.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.i("focus","on yyyy");
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
              actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                Log.i("focus",isUnderAge+"");
                if(isUnderAge){
                    username_reg_ev_dob_row.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    username_reg_ev_dob_row.requestFocus();
                }else{
// NOTHING HAPPENS
//                    email_ev.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
//                    dobYearEt.clearFocus();
                  email_ev.requestFocus();
//                    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//                    mgr.showSoftInput(email_ev, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }

                return false;
            }
```

**Xml**

```
  <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/register"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/sign_up_left_right_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/sign_up_left_right_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_user_name_top_margin">

                <!--<RelativeLayout-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/name_container"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="3">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/firstname_ev"
                            style="@style/RegisterViewStyle"
                            android:hint="  FIRST NAME:"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/middle_ev"
                            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/middle_ev"
                            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/middle_ev"
                            android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/middle_ev"
                            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/middle_ev"/>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/sign_up_names_sep_width"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/middle_ev"
                            style="@style/RegisterViewStyle"
                            android:hint="  MIDDLE INITIAL:"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/lastname_ev"
                            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/lastname_ev"
                            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/lastname_ev"
                            android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/lastname_ev"
                            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/lastname_ev"/>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/sign_up_names_sep_width"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/lastname_ev"
                            style="@style/RegisterViewStyle"
                            android:hint="  LAST NAME:"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/dob_mm_et"
                            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/dob_mm_et"
                            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/dob_mm_et"
                            android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/dob_mm_et"
                            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/dob_mm_et"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/under18_check_box"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:buttonTint="@color/raffle_blue_color"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/under18_tv"
                            android:text="I'm under 18 and/or don't have an email?"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/dob_parent_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <!--android:weightSum="2"-->

                        <LinearLayout
                            style="@style/RegisterViewStyle2"
                            android:id="@+id/dob_container"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_field_sep_margin"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                            <!--style="@style/RegisterViewStyle2"-->
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="DOB:"
                                android:textColor="@color/edit_text_hint_color"
                                android:id="@+id/dob_label_tv"
                                />

                            <!--<EditText-->
                                <!--android:id="@+id/dob_dd_et"-->
                                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:background="@android:color/transparent"-->
                                <!--android:hint="_ _"-->
                                <!--android:textCursorDrawable="@null"-->
                                <!--android:inputType="number"-->
                                <!--android:maxLength="2"-->
                                <!--android:nextFocusForward="@+id/dob_mm_et"-->
                                <!--android:nextFocusRight="@+id/dob_mm_et"-->
                                <!--android:nextFocusDown="@+id/dob_mm_et"-->
                                <!--android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/dob_mm_et"-->
                                <!--android:nextFocusUp="@+id/dob_mm_et"/>-->

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/dob_mm_et"
                                style="@style/RegisterViewStyle"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:hint="MM"
                                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:maxLength="2"
                                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/dob_dd_et"
                                android:nextFocusRight="@+id/dob_dd_et"
                                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/dob_dd_et"
                                android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/dob_dd_et"
                                android:nextFocusUp="@+id/dob_dd_et"/>


                            <TextView
                                android:textColor="@color/edit_text_hint_color"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text=" / "/>

                            <!--<EditText-->
                                <!--android:id="@+id/dob_mm_et"-->
                                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:background="@android:color/transparent"-->
                                <!--android:hint="_ _"-->
                                <!--android:inputType="number"-->
                                <!--android:textCursorDrawable="@null"-->
                                <!--android:maxLength="2"-->
                                <!--android:nextFocusForward="@+id/dob_yyyy_et"-->
                                <!--android:nextFocusRight="@+id/dob_yyyy_et"-->
                                <!--android:nextFocusDown="@+id/dob_yyyy_et"-->
                                <!--android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/dob_yyyy_et"-->
                                <!--android:nextFocusUp="@+id/dob_yyyy_et"/>-->
                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/dob_dd_et"
                                style="@style/RegisterViewStyle"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:hint="DD"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                                android:maxLength="2"
                                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/dob_yyyy_et"
                                android:nextFocusRight="@+id/dob_yyyy_et"
                                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/dob_yyyy_et"
                                android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/dob_yyyy_et"
                                android:nextFocusUp="@+id/dob_yyyy_et"/>


                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text=" / "
                                android:textColor="@color/edit_text_hint_color"/>


                            <EditText
                                style="@style/RegisterViewStyle"
                                android:id="@+id/dob_yyyy_et"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:hint="YYYY"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:maxLength="4"
                                />
                            <!--android:nextFocusForward="@+id/email_ev"-->
                            <!--android:nextFocusRight="@+id/email_ev"-->
                            <!--android:nextFocusDown="@+id/email_ev"-->
                            <!--android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/email_ev"-->
                            <!--android:nextFocusUp="@+id/email_ev"-->
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/email_ev"
                            style="@style/RegisterViewStyle"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_field_sep_margin"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:hint="  EMAIL:"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"

                            />
                        <!--android:nextFocusForward="@+id/password_reg_ev"-->
                        <!--android:nextFocusRight="@+id/password_reg_ev"-->
                        <!--android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password_reg_ev"-->
                        <!--android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/password_reg_ev"-->
                        <!--android:nextFocusUp="@+id/password_reg_ev"-->
                        <!--style="@style/RegisterViewStyle2"-->
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/username_reg_ev_dob_row"
                            style="@style/RegisterViewStyle"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_field_sep_margin"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:hint="  USERNAME:"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/password_reg_ev"
                            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/password_reg_ev"
                            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password_reg_ev"
                            android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/password_reg_ev"
                            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/password_reg_ev"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/username_reg_ev"
                        style="@style/RegisterViewStyle2"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/email_ev"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_field_sep_margin"
                        android:hint="  USERNAME:"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/password_reg_ev"
                        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/password_reg_ev"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password_reg_ev"
                        android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/password_reg_ev"
                        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/password_reg_ev"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/password_reg_ev"
                            style="@style/RegisterViewStyle2"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/username_reg_ev"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_field_sep_margin"
                            android:hint="  PASSWORD:"
                            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/confirm_password_reg_ev"
                            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/confirm_password_reg_ev"
                            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/confirm_password_reg_ev"
                            android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/confirm_password_reg_ev"
                            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/confirm_password_reg_ev"/>

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/confirm_password_reg_ev"
                            style="@style/RegisterViewStyle2"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/password_reg_ev"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_field_sep_margin"
                            android:hint="  CONFIRM PASSWORD:"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/group_code_reg_ev"
                            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/group_code_reg_ev"
                            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/group_code_reg_ev"
                            android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/group_code_reg_ev"
                            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/group_code_reg_ev"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/group_code_reg_ev"
                        style="@style/RegisterViewStyle2"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/confirm_password_reg_ev"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_field_sep_margin"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:hint="  GROUP CODE(OPTIONAL):"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/terms_conditions_signup_checkbox"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:buttonTint="@color/raffle_blue_color"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/terms_conditions_register_message"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/terms_conditions"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/register_btn_rl"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/registration_message"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_btn_top_margin"
                        android:background="@color/raffle_blue_color">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:id="@+id/register_tv"
                            android:padding="6dp"
                            android:text="REGISTER"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/sign_up_edit_text_size"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

I have referred to various solutions but nothing is working

[Set next EditText focused and editable on KEY_DOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133585/set-next-edittext-focused-and-editable-on-key-down)

[requestFocus not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820846/requestfocus-not-working)

[EditText request focus not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586102/edittext-request-focus-not-working)

[requestFocus not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820846/requestfocus-not-working)

Comment: try calling request focus little later i mean in handler say after 500 miliseconds

Comment: @JagjitSingh Not working with handler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What was happening is the I was returning false from onEditorAction- Hence the default editor action was also performed back to back and the focus instantly moved away from the email editText. Now I return true and the deafult action is not performed.Its working correctly now.

```
dobYearEt.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditor ActionListener() {

        @Override

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.i("focus","on yyyy");
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
              actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                Log.i("focus",isUnderAge+"");
                if(isUnderAge){
                    username_reg_ev_dob_row.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    username_reg_ev_dob_row.requestFocus();
                }else{

                  email_ev.requestFocus();

                }
                  return true ; // NOW WORKS
               // return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

U need two xml attributes also to achieve this:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Add them to the EditText as well as the parent layouts. By default these are false, so the focus is not given to the requested view.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:focusable

After u show the EditText based on the checkbox selection, add the next and previous focus points dynamically in code.

Hope this helps.