# Custom Edit Text, listen for Delete Key not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am currently working in a custom EditText to look like the image below, the idea is to always start writing on the left if empty, and work your way to the right jumping from one EditText to the next, but I'm having problems when I try to go back to the previous box, if the current box is empty android won't register the OnKeyListener event so I can't know if Backspace was pressed.

I tried a lot of PinView libraries with success like this one https://github.com/GoodieBag/Pinview, but they don't offer font support so I can't use a custom font with Calligraphy like the image.

Any help with this will be appreciated and also any ideas on how to tidy this mess of coding.

[image: Custom text edits]

Current Code:

```
private void setTextBoxes() {

    // Check status of EditText on focus
    text_2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus && isEditTextEmpty(text_1)) {
                text_1.requestFocus();
            } else if (hasFocus && !isEditTextEmpty(text_2)) {
                text_3.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });

    text_3.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus && isEditTextEmpty(text_2)) {
                text_2.requestFocus();
            } else if (hasFocus && !isEditTextEmpty(text_3)) {
                text_4.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });

    text_4.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus && isEditTextEmpty(text_3)) {
                text_3.requestFocus();
            } else if (hasFocus && !isEditTextEmpty(text_4)) {
                text_5.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });

    text_5.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus && isEditTextEmpty(text_4)) {
                text_4.requestFocus();
            } else if (hasFocus && !isEditTextEmpty(text_5)) {
                text_6.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });

    text_6.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus && isEditTextEmpty(text_5)) {
                text_5.requestFocus();
            } else if (hasFocus && !isEditTextEmpty(text_6)) {
                text_7.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });

    text_7.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus && isEditTextEmpty(text_6)) {
                text_6.requestFocus();
            } else if (hasFocus && !isEditTextEmpty(text_7)) {
                text_8.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });

    text_8.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus && isEditTextEmpty(text_7)) {
                text_7.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });

    // Check for backspaces
    text_2.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Backspace pressed %s", keyCode));
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                text_1.setText("");
                text_1.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    text_3.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                text_2.setText("");
                text_2.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    text_4.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                text_3.setText("");
                text_3.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    text_5.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                text_4.setText("");
                text_4.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    text_6.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                text_5.setText("");
                text_5.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    text_7.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                text_6.setText("");
                text_6.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    text_8.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                text_7.setText("");
                text_7.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    // Go to next EditText
    text_1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                text_2.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });

    text_2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                text_3.requestFocus();
            } else if (s.toString().length() == 0) {
                text_1.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    text_3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                text_4.requestFocus();
            } else if (s.toString().length() == 0) {
                text_2.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    text_4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                text_5.requestFocus();
            } else if (s.toString().length() == 0) {
                text_3.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    text_5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                text_6.requestFocus();
            } else if (s.toString().length() == 0) {
                text_4.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    text_6.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                text_7.requestFocus();
            } else if (s.toString().length() == 0) {
                text_5.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    text_7.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                text_8.requestFocus();
            } else if (s.toString().length() == 0) {
                text_6.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    text_8.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                text_8.requestFocus();
            } else if (s.toString().length() == 0) {
                text_7.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
```

XML (Using Calligraphy for the fonts, this is working ok)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lyt_pin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        fontPath="fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf"
        android:layout_width="36sp"
        android:layout_height="46sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pin_box"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="0"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        fontPath="fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf"
        android:layout_width="36sp"
        android:layout_height="46sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pin_box"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="0"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_3"
        fontPath="fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf"
        android:layout_width="36sp"
        android:layout_height="46sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pin_box"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="0"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_4"
        fontPath="fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf"
        android:layout_width="36sp"
        android:layout_height="46sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pin_box"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="0"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_5"
        fontPath="fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf"
        android:layout_width="36sp"
        android:layout_height="46sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pin_box"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="0"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_6"
        fontPath="fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf"
        android:layout_width="36sp"
        android:layout_height="46sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pin_box"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="0"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_7"
        fontPath="fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf"
        android:layout_width="36sp"
        android:layout_height="46sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pin_box"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="0"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_8"
        fontPath="fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf"
        android:layout_width="36sp"
        android:layout_height="46sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pin_box"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="0"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293470/edittext-requestfocus-dynamically-not-working

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this one in the future, i found a way to keep the library and then find each EditText in the ViewGroup and set the attributes from there programmatically

```
private void traverseEditTexts(ViewGroup v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++) {
        Object child = v.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof EditText) {
            EditText e = (EditText) child;
            e.setTypeface(TypefaceUtils.load(context.getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf"));
            e.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pin_text_color));
            e.setPadding(8,4,8,4);
            e.setTextSize(32);
        }
    }
}
```